# How to display visitor's name by just url?

Tags: wordpress, popup, personalization

I need help to display website visitor's name (on the popups) by just url?

For example this wordpress website:

https://ngantenstory.id/agus-henny/?u=Jonathan

You can change the name to anything and it will display the exact name on the welcome popups.

No need user database, I assume? No need for the user to register first, etc.

How to do this? Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("u"))
```

You can get current page's URL by using `window.location`,

get it's "search parameter" (`"?u=Jonathan"`),

and parse it by create an `URLSearchParams` object,

then get what you want by using `get` method,

finally use `alert` or other thing to show it to user.

`alert` is just for a simple example, don't use it in production, you may want set one of your HTML node's content and style instead.